# I receive an error running pytest on a query set for a proxy model in django

Tags: django, testing

My User model contains the following choices

```
 class Roles(models.TextChoices):
        ACCOUNT_MANAGER = "ACCOUNT_MANAGER", _("Account Manager")
        CLIENT_MANAGER = "CLIENT_MANAGER", _("Client Manager")
        ADMIN = "ADMIN", _("Admin")

    base_role = Roles.ACCOUNT_MANAGER
```

I have then created a proxy model and manager

```
class ACManager(models.Manager):
    # Ensures queries on the Account Manager model return only Account Managers
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return results.filter(role=User.Roles.ACCOUNT_MANAGER)


class AccountManager(User):
    # This sets the user role to Account Manager during record creation
    base_role = User.Roles.ACCOUNT_MANAGER
    objects = ACManager()
```

I have the following test

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_ac_manager_get_queryset():
    # Test setting user roles
    role = User.Roles.ACCOUNT_MANAGER
    user = User.objects.create_user(email="test@example.com", password="password123", role=role)

    # Create an instance of ACManager
    manager = ACManager()

    # Call the get_queryset method
    queryset = manager.get_queryset()

    # Assert that only users with the ACCOUNT_MANAGER role are in the queryset
    assert user in queryset

    assert queryset.count() == 1
```

When I run the test I get the following error message
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'role' into field.

Creating users with the different roles works so I am a bit confused as to why this is happening.
Any help on resolving this issue would be appreciated.